# Find the time complexity of the function "foo"

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm struggling to find the **time complexity** of this function:

```
void foo(int n) {
    int i, m = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        m *= n; // (m = n^n) ??
    }
    while (m > 1) {
        m /= 3;
    }
}
```

Well, the first for iteration is clearly `O(n^n)`, the explanation to it is because `m started with value 1`, and multiplies itself `n` times.

Now, we start the while loop with `m = n^n` and we divide it every time by `3`.
which means, (I guess), `log(n^n)`.

Assuming I got it right up till now, I'm not sure if I need to sum or multiply, but my logic says I need to sum them, because *they* are 'odd' to each other.

So my assumption is: `O(n^n) + O(log(n^n)) = O(n^n)` Because if n is quite big, we can just refrain from `O(log(n^n))`.

Well, I really made many assumptions here, and I hope that makes sense. I'd love to hear your opinions about the time complexity of this function.

Comment: But the loop still goes n times in the first one so it is O(n)

Comment: Btw, `m *= n;` = `m = m * n;`

Comment: @camel-man Oh right, and btw, O(n) > O(log(n^n))? if yes, why?

Comment: O(log(n^n)) ~ O(n log(n)) > O(n)

Comment: The size of `n` is limited in C, the function will have undefined behavior for all but very small values of `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, time complexity is `O(n log n)` because:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
   m *= n;
```

this will be executed n times and in the end `m=n^n`

Then this

```
while (m>1)
   m /= 3;
```

will be executed `log3(n^n)` times which is `n * log3(n)`:

**P.S.** But this is only if you count number of operations. In real life it takes much more time to calculate `n^n` because the numbers become too big. Also your function will overflow when you will be multiplying such big numbers and most probably you will be bounded by the maximum number of `int` (in which case the complexity will be `O(n)`)

Comment: Assuming I'm not bound by maximum number, the answer will be n * log3(n) = O(n * log(n)) right?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS yes, but then it can't be written in c in a way you wrote it.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your time and effort you put here sir.

Answer (score 0):

With `foo(int n)` and 32-bit `int`, `n` cannot exceed the magnitude of 10, else `m *= n` overflows.

Given such a small range that `n` works, the O() seems moot.  Even with 64-bit unsigned `m`, `n <= 15`.

So I suppose O(n lg(n)) is technically correct, but given the constraints of `int`, suspect code took more time to do a single `printf()` than iterate through `foo(10)`.  IOWs it is *practically* O(1).

```
unsigned long long foo(int n) {
  unsigned long long cnt = 0;
  int i;
  unsigned long long m = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (m >= ULLONG_MAX/n) exit(1);
    m *= n; // (m = n^n) ??
    cnt++;
  }
  while (m > 1) {
    m /= 3;
    cnt++;
  }
  return cnt;
}
```

And came up with

```
1 1
2 3
3 6
4 9
5 12
6 16
7 19
8 23
9 27
10 31
11 35
12 39
13 43
14 47
15 52
```